# How can I auto dismiss Android VideoView on Dialog?

Tags: android, dialog, popup, android-videoview

When I read a NFC tag, I play the video on videoview on dialog pop up. I want to dialog dismiss when the video finih. How can I code this?

Comment: Set an `OnCompletionListener` on the `VideoView`. `onCompletion`, call `Dialog.dismiss()`

Comment: Great! For closure I have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set an `OnCompletionListener` on the `VideoView`.

In the `onCompletion` call, call `dialog.dismiss()`

```
videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        dialog.dismiss();    
    }
});
```

[VideoView.setOnCompletionListener(MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener l)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#setOnCompletionListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener%29)

[Dialog.dismiss()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#dismiss%28%29)

Comment: yeah I coded same, thats usefull way. Thanks again Ken Wolf :)